# Python how to make an executable from a text file

Tags: python, executable

So what i want to do is write a .exe bynary to  a .txt file and then write the .txt file to a .exe bynary, i tried this:

```
with open("old_File.exe", "rb") as f:
    text_file = open("File.txt", "w")
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        text_file.write(str(byte))
        byte = f.read(1)
text_file.close()

with open("New_File.exe", "wb") as f:
    text_file = open("File.txt", "r")
    byte = text_file.read(12)
    while byte != "":
        print byte
        f.write(byte)
        byte = text_file.read(12)
text_file.close()
f.close()
```

but if i run the `New_File.exe` windows tels me it is not a valid aplication.
What am  doing wrong?

Comment: Writing the bits of an executable to a file doesn't make the file an executable. You may want to look into py2exe or some similar package. http://www.py2exe.org/ . But, why do you want to do this?

Comment: if the source file is an executable, at least your code works in Ubuntu as it generates exactly the same output. Nonetheless I don't know how executables work in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i foud the answer myself:

```
exe = open("exe.exe", "rb")
txt = open("txt.txt", "wb")
data = exe.read(100000)
while data != "":
    txt.write(data)
    data = exe.read(100000)
exe.close()
txt.close()
```

you actually have to write the binary on the text file instead of writing it as a string on the file itself.

```
    #create new file
N_exe = open("N-exe.exe", "w+")
N_exe.close()


N_exe = open("N-exe.exe", "wb")
Txt = open("txt.txt", "rb")

data = Txt.read(100000)
while data != "":
    N_exe.write(data)
    data = Txt.read(100000)

N_exe.close()
Txt.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

The second time you were reading the *.txt file, you didn't open it in read binary mode, just in read, which is in fact, read text mode.
With older versions of Python it was platform dependent, i.e. this will be a problem only on Windows.
In Python 3, this will make you a problem on any platform.

Advice: Don't read a file in so small chunks if you don't have to, you will throttle poor Windows. Do it with at least 1024. It's often done with 4096 bytes. If the file is small, just do newfile.write(oldfile.read()) Todays PCs have enough RAM to put few MB in it without any problem. 
And, there is no need for str(byte) as it is already a string.

Answer (score 1):

To copy two files and preserve metadata, use [shutil.copy2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2). This is a much safer way to copy files.

Comment: the question wasn't how to copy a file. Although, yes, shutil will do it nicely.